# the ',' automatically split a line into 3 rows

Tags: python, csv, writer

I have a for loop, in which i have a line

> I am happy,how are you,fine that thankyou

When i write this to a csv file it is splitting into 3 rows :

I am happy -1st row

how are you- 2nd row

fine that thankyou -3rd row

How can i get everything into the 1st row?

```
for item in soup.select('div.view-content ol li'):
    with open('small.csv','a') as f1:
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='    ',lineterminator='\n',)
        for elm in soup.findAll("h4"):
            for a in elm.findAll('a'):
                texts=a.text
                texts=texts.replace(",", ";")
                linked=a.get('href')
                link='http://www.india.gov.in'+linked
                link=link.replace("http://",result+"http://")
                link=link+"\n"
                f1.seek(0)
                writer.writerow(texts)
inFile = open('small.csv','r')
outFile = open('large.csv','w')
listLines = []
for line in inFile:
if line in listLines:
    continue
else:
    outFile.write(line)
    listLines.append(line)
outFile.close()

inFile.close()
```

Comment: what kind of object is 'csv'? I mean the object which calls writer().

Comment: @Emisilve86 i have updated the code can you please look into that

Comment: Is the problem in `small.csv` or in `large.csv` ? And if in `small.csv` could you spy what are the values of `texts` that you write with `writer.writerows(texts)` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the problem is existing in both small and large.csv